# Trying to execute shell script using camel route & facing the following issue

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to execute shell script with camel and tried the following code, everything is looking fine its starting the route but I have following 2 issues

1. Shell script file is not picking and executing the commands in it.
2. Not even getting log messages that I kept all over in my code.

following is the route that I am using

```
@component
public class ShellRoute extends RouteBuilder
{
@override
public void configure()
{
final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ShellRoute.class);
logger.info("shellRoute");

boolean startupRoute=true;

from("direct:start")
.log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Enter into Route:")
.routeID("ShellRoute")
.autoStartup(startupRoute)
.onException(Exception.class);
.logExhausted(false)
.logStackTrace(false)
.end()
.log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Starting Script:")
.to("exec:./run_setup.sh?args=dev")
.log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "End of Script:");
}
}
```

Following is the Log:

> **2017-09-29 08:32:53 INFO  Version:30** - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final
>
> **2017-09-29 08:32:53 INFO  SupportMain:48** - Starting SupportMain on VDDP13C-52C8C99.mis.lmig.com with PID 13002
>   (/data/userdata/workspaces/ClaimDownload/support/target/classes
>   started by mani in /data/userdata/workspaces/ClaimDownload/support)
>
> **2017-09-29 08:32:53 INFO  SupportMain:669** - The following profiles are active: local
>
> **2017-09-29 08:32:53 INFO  AnnotationConfigApplicationContext:581** - Refreshing
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@776aec5c:
>   startup date [Fri Sep 29 08:32:53 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>   2017-09-29 08:32:55 INFO 
>   PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker:328 - Bean
>   'org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelAutoConfiguration' of type [class
>   org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9509da1]
>   is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for
>   example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
>
> **2017-09-29 08:32:56 INFO  DefaultTypeConverter:56** - Loaded 209 type converters
>
> **2017-09-29 08:32:57 INFO  AnnotationMBeanExporter:431** - Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
>
> **2017-09-29 08:32:57 INFO  ShellRoute:33** - ShellRoute
>
> **2017-09-29 08:32:57 INFO  RoutesCollector:148** - Loading additional Camel XML routes from: classpath:camel/*.xml
>
> **2017-09-29 08:32:57 INFO  RoutesCollector:162** - Loading additional Camel XML rests from: classpath:camel-rest/*.xml
>
> **2017-09-29 08:32:57 INFO  SpringCamelContext:2800** - Apache Camel 2.17.2 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
>
> **2017-09-29 08:32:57 INFO  ManagedManagementStrategy:191** - JMX is enabled
>
> **2017-09-29 08:32:57 INFO  DefaultRuntimeEndpointRegistry:203** - Runtime endpoint registry is in extended mode gathering usage
>   statistics of all incoming and outgoing endpoints (cache limit: 1000)
>
> **2017-09-29 08:32:57 INFO  SpringCamelContext:3039** - AllowUseOriginalMessage is enabled. If access to the original message
>   is not needed, then its recommended to turn this option off as it may
>   improve performance.
>
> **2017-09-29 08:32:57 INFO  SpringCamelContext:3049** - StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream
>   caching. See more details at
>   http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
>
> **2017-09-29 08:32:57 INFO  SpringCamelContext:3570** - Route: ShellRoute started and consuming from: Endpoint[direct://start]
>
> **2017-09-29 08:32:57 INFO  SpringCamelContext:2840** - Total 1 routes, of which 1 are started.
>
> **2017-09-29 08:32:57 INFO  SpringCamelContext:2841** - Apache Camel 2.17.2 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.667 seconds
>
> **2017-09-29 08:32:57 INFO  SupportMain:57** - Started SupportMain in 4.963 seconds (JVM running for 6.767)
>
> **2017-09-29 08:32:57 INFO  AnnotationConfigApplicationContext:982** - Closing
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@776aec5c:
>   startup date [Fri Sep 29 08:32:53 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>
> **2017-09-29 08:32:57 INFO  AnnotationMBeanExporter:449** - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
>
> **2017-09-29 08:32:57 INFO  SpringCamelContext:3066** - Apache Camel 2.17.2 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutting down

Answer (score 0):

To execute shell script command in Apache camel, As per the exec component documentation http://camel.apache.org/exec.html

The following example executes Apache Ant (Windows only) with the build file CamelExecBuildFile.xml, provided that ant.bat is in the system path, and that CamelExecBuildFile.xml is in the current directory.

`from("direct:exec").to("exec:ant.bat?args=-f CamelExecBuildFile.xml")`

So similarly 
`from("direct:exec").to("exec:{path}/Cygwin/bin/bash?args=run_setup.sh")`

Comment: Hi ManishGupta

It's not working, problem here in this route is, route is starting as I gave 
.autoStartup(startupRoute)

But whatever in the route it may be "exec" or "simple file transfer" its not happening

Do I need to register this route somewhere to execute commands in the route

Please let me know, i am new to camel.

Comment: A good idea is to study the beginner examples of Apache Camel if you are new to Camel: https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples#examples

Answer (score 0):

The direct endpoint provides synchronous invocation of a route. So you have to invoke the route for the script to execute.
Have a look at this answer for invoking routes. [Apache Camel : "direct:start" endpoint - what does it mean ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636651/apache-camel-directstart-endpoint-what-does-it-mean)

If you want it to execute just one time at the startup you can replace

```
from("direct:exec")
```

with something like

```
from("timer://runOnce?repeatCount=1&delay=5000")
```

Related answer in [Apache Camel - Triggering a task on startup to run only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714211/apache-camel-triggering-a-task-on-startup-to-run-only-once)