# Cannot query MongoDb on producer endpoint using direct component

Tags: spring, mongodb, apache-camel

I have configured the following route to query my local MongoDB instance.
The instance is running on localhost on port 27017 without authentication.

The route is:

```
from("direct:start")
    .to("mongodb:mongoBean?" +
    "database=camel-source" +
    "&collection=RacingEvents" +
    "&operation=getDbStats")        
    .convertBodyTo(String.class)
    .to("file://E:/data/test.txt");
```

My mongoBean is defined in spring as:

```
<bean id="mongoBean" class="com.mongodb.Mongo">
        <constructor-arg name="host" value="localhost" />
        <constructor-arg name="port" value="27017" />
</bean>
```

The route starts up fine but no data is sent to the file endpoint.

If I replace the direct: component endpoint with a timer: component data is written to the file endpoint:

```
from("timer://foo?delay=1&repeatCount=1")
        .to("mongodb:mongoBean?" +
        "database=camel-source" +
        "&collection=RacingEvents" +
        "&operation=getDbStats")        
        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
        .to("file://E:/data/test.txt");
```

The question is why does the direct component not initiate the call to MongoDB but the timer component does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `direct` component only routes if you send a message to it, its like a direct method invocation in Java, eg when you call a method on a java instance. The `timer` on the other hand runs indpendently, and triggeres a new empty message every X period.

See more details at

- http://camel.apache.org/direct
- http://camel.apache.org/timer

And a bit in this FAQ

- http://camel.apache.org/how-do-the-direct-event-seda-and-vm-endpoints-compare.html

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. To send a message to the endpoint at route start I could then use the method you outlined in http://stackoverflow.com/a/7727197/600775 using a ProducerTemplate, correct?

Comment: Yeah a ProducerTemplate allows to send a message to any Camel endpoint from Java code (to produce a message to an endpoint). Then the consumer on that endpoint would be able to route it (though a few endpoints dont accept producers such as a timer)

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you for your help.